# WebKit delegate method not working (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, delegates, webkit

I am trying to implement a delegate method for my Cocoa document-based application which uses WebKit. I don't have much experience with delegates, so I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly. The code is below.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didReceiveTitle:(NSString *)title forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {


// Report feedback only for the main frame.

if (frame == [sender mainFrame]) {

    [[sender window] setTitle:title];

}
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your webView. Using your Connection Inspector connect the frameLoadDelegate to your appController object ...

like this:

[image]

Comment: Got it working now, I forgot to add `[webViewThing setFrameLoadDelegate:self];` hahaha.